# Basis whose integral is a basis

Tags: measure-theory, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal

What is a simple example of a set of functions $\{e_i\}$ in $L^2_w$ which form an orthonormal basis and satisfy the property that:
\begin{equation}
\langle e_i(t)\int_{-\infty}^t e_j(s)ds , e_k(t) \rangle_{L^2_w} = \delta_{i=k \mbox{ or } j=k}
\end{equation}

(If this is too much to ask, change the righthand-side to $\delta_{i=j=k}$.  )

Where $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}w(s)ds =1$ and $L^2_w$ is the $L^2$-space weighted by $w$.

Comment: Are you assuming a complex Hilbert space? Otherwise the product $\langle e_i(t) \int_{-\infty}^t e_j(s) ds, e_k(t)\rangle$ is symmetric in $i$ and $k$, but the right hand side $\delta_{i = k \text{ or } j= k}$ is not, which says that the equality is impossible. The version $\delta_{i = j = k}$ implies that $e_i(t) \int_{-\infty}^t e_i(s) ds = e_i(t)$. This requires $\int_{-\infty}^t e_i(s)ds = 1$ for every $t$, but that means $e_i \equiv 0$. This holds for all $i$, again gives a contradiction.

Comment: Are you sure you asked the question you intended to ask?

Comment: Ah ok, so it's not possible then.  Thanks!